# AndroidStudio: Can't run AVD because of Intel HAXM error. Failed to run

Tags: android-studio

[yesterday night I downloaded Android Studio and this is the error I got, how to fix this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cjnbx.jpg)

Comment: What CPU do you have? Can you go to your BIOS menu and enable VT-x or SVM under the CPU options?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Intel HAXM driver by going to SDK Manager > SDK Tools.